# Ejecutar python en crontab macOs Monterrey

Tags: crontab

Estoy empezando a utilizar crontab para ejecutar un script de python 3.9.12. Esta es la tarea que quiero programar.

`40 * * * * * /Users/guillermohernandez/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/guillermohernandez/Desktop/programacion/Mundial/Code/prueba.py`

ya di el permiso chmod ugo+x prueba.py a la hora que se debe ejecutar la tarea no lo hace y recibo un mail que dice los siguiente: /bin/sh: Desktop: command not found.
Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: valdiastes si en tu script tiene el bin bash al principio???/

Comment: No, como se hace eso? El script que estoy intentando ejecutar ahorita es una prueba y solo imprime un texto, pero el que quiero automatizar es para hacer web scraping con selenium y guardar la informacion en tablas sql. Lo que me comentas como se hace??

Comment: y si intentas haciendo un which `python3` para saber la ruta de tu python por defecto creo que es `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Al ejecutar which python3 me da esto: /Users/guillermohernandez/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3

Comment: Agregue la linea ```#!/usr/bin/python``` al inicio del script y sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: luego de tu script as una redireccion con `>> /Users/guillermohernandez/Desktop/programacion/Mundial/Code/out.log` para ver el log de errores o cualquier cosa que salga!

Comment: Volvi a programar la tarea para que se ejecutara, espere a la hora y sigo obteniendo el mismo mail ´´´/bin/sh: Desktop: command not found´´´ Luego de revisar el mail ejecute ´´´>> /Users/guillermohernandez/Desktop/programacion/Mundial/Code/out.log´´´ y se creo un archivo out.log en la carpeta pero la terminal se queda en "pausa" parece que esta ejecutando algo pero no tiene ningún mensaje. En que paso me equivoqué?